# GPL licensed software installed on commercial hardware

Tags: licensing, hardware, gpl

Do vendors need to provide sources, at the customer's request, for GPL licensed software installed on the hardware they sell?

For example, a vendor sells an IPTV box and pre-installs some proprietary software product which is linked with some GPLed library. As a consequence, the software becomes GPLed itself.
Does the vendor need to provide the source code for it? The vendor doesn't sell that software, he sells hardware.

Comment: More details, please. Lots of libraries are available in LGPL form, where you can use them without the using code becoming GPL.

Comment: The question is about GPL license not LGPL

Comment: the number of people who don't know the difference is very large, that's why it's a comment.

Comment: Vendor should have already known that. And by what you outline was in the need to provide a written statement to provide sources when client asks for it. I wonder you ask now. Does the client not have any written statement? Which IPTV box?

Comment: Not only does the vendor need to provide source code, he has to be somewhat pro-active: either provide it with the TV, or at least provide the offer for source code with the TV. He's already in violation if he didn't do either, but since the GPLv3 that's a curable condition.

Comment: vendor can use GPL-condom (a LGPL-wrapper to a GPL library)

Comment: See also: [Open Source Stack Exchange: Hardware with GPL firmware](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/a/4721/17713)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes - the GPL says nothing about "selling" software, it talks about distributing.
If you distribute GPL software you have to abide by the licence.

The GPL3 uses a slightly different phrase "convey" - to clear up some different meanings of "distribute" in different jurisidictions

Comment: The distinction you're making between "selling" the software and "conveying" it seems insignificant to me, unless you're talking about some sort of software delivery that's not considered "conveyance," such as a web interface.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - it's important. I can't reuse GPL code and not release the source simply because I'm not charging money for the result. Otherwise people could get around GPL source clause simply by giving away the binary for free and charging for hardware/dongle/license/etc.

Answer (score 11):

In short, yes. When it was revealed that some of the more popular wireless routers were using an open source core, (without the vendors publishing the source) many people were up in arms about it. If the software is being redistributed outside of your company, the GPL takes effect.

Comment: @AlexanderReshytko: if you like the answer, please approve it.

Comment: @comingstorm: done)

Comment: @AlexanderReshytko - you need to "accept" the best answer by clicking the tick mark next to it.

Comment: @detly twice i find you in 2 days

Answer (score 0):

The long answer is that you should read the terms of the GPL and see whether what you're doing constitutes distribution and what your responsibilities are.

The short answer, for most forms of copying GPL'd software, is "yes."

Comment: Would the downvoter care to expound on what makes this answer worse than Martin's, which says essentially the same thing?

Comment: (Not my downvote) "depending on the license" and "generally" are unnecessary here. All versions of the GPL are clear enough for the specific case given; it doesn't depend.

Comment: That's fair enough.  Revised accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

**In short:** Yes, as it is states in the reference: "The GPL is the first copyleft license for general use, which means that derived works can only be distributed under the same license terms." - reference is here.